# Java | Problem with the .clear() function

Tags: java

Ok, this is my second time posting here, so forgive me if I'm giving too much information (and for the poor state of my code). This is an excerpt from a larger program I'm playing around with, but I've run into a slight problem. The .clear() function is coming up with an error at odd times and I cannot pinpoint why. This function here is designed to show relevant personality types according to inputs (input "es" brings up "es" personality types). It is designed to take inputs of length 0-4.

```
package MBTI_Experiment;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MBTI_Root {
    protected int counter = 0;
    protected List<String> selected_f = new ArrayList<>();
    protected List<String> selected_t = new ArrayList<>();
    protected String[] selected_t_1 = new String[16];
    protected String[] selected_t_2 = new String[8];
    protected String[] selected_t_3 = new String[4];
    protected String[] selected_t_4 = new String[2];
    protected double[] percentages = new double[] {0.0, 0.0};
    protected char[] functions = new char[] {'*', '*', '*', '*'};
    protected String[] types_array = new String[] {"intj", "intp", "entj", "entp", "infj", "infp", "enfj", "enfp",
                                                    "istj", "isfj", "estj", "esfj", "istp", "isfp", "estp", "esfp"};
    protected double[] m_percentages = new double[] {3.3, 4.8, 2.7, 4.0, 1.2, 4.1, 2.7, 6.4,
                                                        16.4, 8.1, 11.2, 7.5, 8.5, 7.6, 5.6, 6.9};
    protected double[] f_percentages = new double[] {0.9, 1.7, 0.9, 2.4, 1.6, 4.6, 3.3, 9.7,

                                                     6.9, 19.4, 6.3, 16.9, 2.3, 9.9, 3.0, 10.1};
 public MBTI_Root() {
        boolean valid = true;       // Resets boolean at the start of function
        while (valid) {
            reset_Percentages();
            System.out.println("\nBelow is a list of possible functions.");
            System.out.println("\n 1.  Run Gender Distribution \n 2.  Run Gender Distribution by Letter " +
                    "\n 3.  Run Gender Distribution by Function ");
            System.out.println(" 4.  Retrieve Type Information \n 0.  Terminate Program ");
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter the Number of the Desired Function.");
            Scanner input_1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option = input_1.nextInt();

// Cut, but continues...

            else if (option == 2) {
                boolean cont = true;
                while (cont) {
                    reset_Selected_number(selected_t_1);
                    reset_Selected_number(selected_t_2);
                    reset_Selected_number(selected_t_3);
                    reset_Selected_number(selected_t_4);
                    reset_Selected_t();
                    reset_Percentages();
                    reset_Selected_f();
                    reset_Functions();
                    System.out.println("\nEnter the letter for desired functions. ");
                    Scanner input_3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String function = input_3.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                    MBTI_Function_2(function);
                    System.out.println("\nSelected function(s): " + selected_f.toString().substring(1,
                            selected_f.toString().length() - 1) + ".");
                    boolean not_empty = true;
                    for (String occupant : selected_t) {
                        if (occupant.isEmpty()) {
                            not_empty = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (not_empty) {
                        System.out.println("Types that include these functions: " + selected_t.toString().substring
                                (1, selected_t.toString().length() - 1).toUpperCase());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("There are no types that include this combination of functions.");
                    }
                    cont = return_to_root("Enter more inputs?");
                }
            }
```

The important part of this is that it calls the below function and uses the above arrays and lists. Here is the relevant function:

```
public void MBTI_Function_2(String function) {
        boolean introverted = function.contains("i");
        boolean extroverted = function.contains("e");
        boolean intuitive = function.contains("n");
        boolean sensing = function.contains("s");
        boolean thinking = function.contains("t");
        boolean feeling = function.contains("f");
        boolean judging = function.contains("j");
        boolean perceiving = function.contains("p");
        if (introverted) {
            selected_f.add("Introverted");
        }
        if (extroverted) {
            selected_f.add("Extroverted");
        }
        if (intuitive) {
            selected_f.add("Intuitive");
        }
        if (sensing) {
            selected_f.add("Sensing");
        }
        if (thinking) {
            selected_f.add("Thinking");
        }
        if (feeling) {
            selected_f.add("Feeling");
        }
        if (judging) {
            selected_f.add("Judging");
        }
        if (perceiving) {
            selected_f.add("Perceiving");
        }
        if (function.isEmpty()) {
            return_to_root("\nInvalid Input. Return to Root?");
        }
        search(function);
    }
protected void search(String function) {
        for (int i = 0; i < function.length(); i++) {
            functions[i] = function.charAt(i);
        }
        boolean remain = true;
        System.arraycopy(types_array, 0, selected_t_1, 0, 16);
        if (remain) {
            reset_Counter();
            for (String type : selected_t_1) {
                if (type.contains(String.valueOf(functions[0]))) {
                    selected_t_2[counter] = type;
                    counter++;
                } else if (functions[0] == '*') {
                    selected_t = Arrays.asList(selected_t_1);
                    remain = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (remain) {
            reset_Counter();
            for (String type : selected_t_2) {
                if (type.contains(String.valueOf(functions[1]))) {
                    selected_t_3[counter] = type;
                    counter++;
                } else if (functions[1] == '*') {
                    selected_t = Arrays.asList(selected_t_2);
                    remain = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (remain) {
            reset_Counter();
            for (String type : selected_t_3) {
                if (type.contains(String.valueOf(functions[2]))) {
                    selected_t_4[counter] = type;
                    counter++;
                } else if (functions[2] == '*') {
                    selected_t = Arrays.asList(selected_t_3);
                    remain = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (remain) {
            reset_Counter();
            for (String type : selected_t_4) {
                if (type.contains(String.valueOf(functions[3]))) {
                    selected_t.add(type);
                    counter++;
                } else if (functions[3] == '*') {
                    selected_t = Arrays.asList(selected_t_4);
                    remain = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This can certainly be improved and condensed, but it works. Right now, the functions require that I reset the arrays and lists after each completion, and that's where I run into my problem.

```
    protected void reset_Percentages() {
        percentages[0] = 0.0;
        percentages[1] = 0.0;
    }
    protected void reset_Selected_f() {
        selected_f.clear();
    }
    protected void reset_Functions() {
        Arrays.fill(functions, '*');
    }
    protected void reset_Counter() {
        counter = 0;
    }
    protected void reset_Selected_t() {
        selected_t.clear();
    }
    protected void reset_Selected_number(String[] function) {
        Arrays.fill(function, "");
    }
```

Specifically, I'm having problems with reset_Selected_t(), which uses the .clear() method. I get an error whenever the input is smaller than 4 characters. 
This was a really long and round-about way of getting to this question, but why am I having trouble with this clear function? Its cousin reset_Selected_f() works fine.

Comment: What is the error you get (i.e. stack trace)?

Comment: You wrote: _The .clear() function is coming up with an error_ Please [edit] your question and provide details of the error you are getting.

Comment: Yeah, less "it's my second time more posting here" and more **clear, specific, technical details** (stack traces, error messages).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are lines like `selected_t = Arrays.asList(selected_t_1);`

`Arrays.asList` doesn't create a new list based on the contents of the array; it wraps the existing array in a list. As such, changes to the list will be reflected in the array.

In this case, the method `.clear()` creates a problem since it removes all elements from the list. This is impossible to do to the inner array; it's always a fixed size. As such, it throws an exception.

The same thing would happen if you tried to use `add` or `remove` on a list created by `Array.asList`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Arrays.asList() with

```
selected_t = Arrays.stream(selected_t_1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
selected_t = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(selected_t_1));
```